# Selecting values with Pandas multiindex using lists of tuples

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex with 3 levels:

```
id    foo  bar    col1
0     1    a -0.225873
      2    a -0.275865
      2    b -1.324766
3     1    a -0.607122
      2    a -1.465992
      2    b -1.582276
      3    b -0.718533
7     1    a -1.904252
      2    a  0.588496
      2    b -1.057599
      3    a  0.388754
      3    b -0.940285
```

Preserving the id index level, I want to sum along the foo and bar levels, but with different values for each id.

For example, for id = 0 I want to sum over foo = [1] and bar = [["a", "b"]], for id = 3 I want to sum over foo = [2] and bar = [["a", "b"]], and for id = 7 I want to sum over foo = [[1,2]] and bar = [["a"]]. Giving the result:

```
id    col1
0     -0.225873    
3     -3.048268   
7     -1.315756
```

I have been trying something along these lines:

```
df.loc(axis = 0)[[(0, 1, ["a","b"]), (3, 2, ["a","b"]), (7, [1,2], "a")].sum()
```

Not sure if this is even possible. Any elegant solution (possibly removing the MultiIndex?) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of tuples is not the problem.  The fact that each tuple does not correspond to a *single index* is the problem (Since a `list` isn't a valid `key`).  If you want to index a Dataframe like this, you need to expand the lists inside each tuple to their own entries.

---

Define your options like the following list of dictionaries, then transform using a list comprehension and index using all individual entries.

```
d = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'foo': [1],
    'bar': ['a', 'b']
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'foo': [2],
    'bar': ['a', 'b']
  },
  {
    'id': 7,
    'foo': [1, 2],
    'bar': ['a']
  },
]
```

---

```
all_idx = [
    (el['id'], i, j)
    for el in d
    for i in el['foo']
    for j in el['bar']
]

# [(0, 1, 'a'), (0, 1, 'b'), (3, 2, 'a'), (3, 2, 'b'), (7, 1, 'a'), (7, 2, 'a')]

df.loc[all_idx].groupby(level=0).sum()
```

```
        col1
id
0  -0.225873
3  -3.048268
7  -1.315756
```

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct solution using [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
sections = [(0, 1, slice(None)), (3, 2, slice(None)), (7, slice(1,2), "a")]
pd.concat(df.loc[s] for s in sections).groupby("id").sum()
```

```
        col1
id          
0  -0.225873
3  -3.048268
7  -1.315756
```

Two things to note:

1. This may be less memory-efficient than the accepted answer since `pd.concat` creates a new DataFrame.
2. The `slice(None)`'s are mandatory, otherwise the index columns of the `df.loc[s]`'s mismatch when calling `pd.concat`.